# How to make form in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, forms, file-upload

I'm confuse how to make new form in Wordpress

this form can upload file too
and will be saved in new table I created

or can I use [Contact7] ??

if can, where I can change the table destination?

Comment: Yes, you can use `Contact form 7` plugin, it is fastest way to make forms for newbies. Keep in mind, that this plugin is used mostly for contact information purposes, not file uploads.

Comment: so is there any plugin to help me?
to upload multiple file?

Comment: Yes, of course, plenty of them, search in plugins database at www.wordrpess.org

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
You should use contact-form-7 wordpress plugin.

Take this from:
```

https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/

```
You will get all solutions here.
```

-- 
Thanks